# Not able to fetch the between dates from 2 dates of timestamp in swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, date

I am getting two time stamps from server response. Like following

```
    value = 1507824000; //2017-10-12 16:00:00 +0000
    value2 = 1507939200; //2017-10-14 00:00:00 +0000

      let startTimeStamp = dateTimeStampValues["value"] as! String
      let endTimeStamp = dateTimeStampValues["value2"] as! String


     let convertedDate = Double(startTimeStamp)

     let convertedEndDate = Double(endTimeStamp)

     var startdate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: convertedDate!) 


     let enddate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: convertedEndDate!) 
    self.showRange(between: startdate, and: enddate)

func showRange(between startDate: Date, and endDate: Date) {
    guard startDate < endDate else { return }

    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let calendarEndDate = calendar.startOfDay(for: endDate)

    var currentDate = calendar.startOfDay(for: startDate)

    while(currentDate <= calendarEndDate) {
        print(currentDate)
        currentDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: currentDate)!
        let dateString = currentDate.convertDateToString(withFormat: "MMM-dd-yyyy h:mm a")
        self.totalDaysFromServerArray.append(dateString)
        print("\(self.totalDaysFromServerArray)")
    }
}
```

But, the out put is

```
self.totalDaysFromServerArray is ["Oct-13-2017 12:00 AM", "Oct-14-2017 12:00 AM", "Oct-15-2017 12:00 AM"]
```

but, it should print from 
Oct-12-2017 to Oct-14-17

Can anyone suggest me, where its going wrong in my code, thanks.

Comment: both the value is Sun Jan 18 1970 16:20:24 GMT+0530, if you convert to date - http://www.ruddwire.com/handy-code/date-to-millisecond-calculators/#.WhQlgkyB0yk

Comment: @AbdulKarim : there is nothing to do with this. Because both values are right! if you convert them in date then it will return `2017-10-12 16:00:00 +0000` and `2017-10-14 00:00:00 +0000`.

Answer (score 0):

If you will print your `startdate` and `enddate` directly(without converting in string) it will be print `2017-10-12 16:00:00 +0000` and `2017-10-14 00:00:00 +0000` respectively because it will be in `UTC` format. When you will convert that date to string then it will be in your local timezone! For example, If you are in `india` then your timezone will be `GMT + 05:30` or `UTC + 05:30`, so it will add `05 : 30` hours in your date while converting to string.

So, there is nothing wrong in your code. Your result dates are in `gmt + 05 : 30` time zone as you has converted them to string.

Now, If someone in `UK` do this then he/she will find it in their local timezone! I mean they will get output what you expect in your question because UK's timezone is `UTC + 00 : 00` or `GMT + 00 : 00`

Now if you want to show your string value also in `utc` or any specific timezone OR if you want to prevent above scenario when you convert date to string then you can set specific timezone! then it will convert date to string in that timezone(see below example for that). But it is not proper way unless you hardly required it because normal behavior is that you shows date in local timezone to users.

For example,

```
 let value = "1507824000" //2017-10-12 16:00:00 +0000
    let value2 = "1507939200" //2017-10-14 00:00:00 +0000

    let convertedDate = Double(value)

    let convertedEndDate = Double(value2)

    let startdate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: convertedDate!)


    let enddate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: convertedEndDate!)
    self.showRange(between: startdate, and: enddate)
```

and your function will be,

```
   func showRange(between startDate: Date, and endDate: Date) {
    guard startDate < endDate else { return }

    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let calendarEndDate = calendar.startOfDay(for: endDate)

    var currentDate = calendar.startOfDay(for: startDate)

    while(currentDate <= calendarEndDate) {
        print(currentDate)
        currentDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: currentDate)!
        let df = DateFormatter.init()
        df.dateFormat = "MMM-dd-yyyy h:mm a"
        df.timeZone = TimeZone.init(abbreviation: "BST")

        let dateString = df.string(from: currentDate)
        totalDaysFromServerArray.append(dateString)

    }
    print("\(totalDaysFromServerArray)")
}
```

And your result will be,

```
  Oct-12-2017 7:30 PM Oct-13-2017 7:30 PM Oct-14-2017 7:30 PM
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: Thanks for valuable reply, But, Time zone should be according to device settings only need to be show. Like If my device is GMT it should be in GMT, and other person device is like UTC, it should be in UTC format.

Comment: Yeah that’s I am saying that nothing is wrong in your code. You should not manually set timezone!